# Create a IBM i Java Toolkit RecordFormat from an IBM i File

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, jt400

Can a jt400 RecordFormat object be created just by pointing to a System i db file with a Path?

I can create the RecordFormat and add the Field definitions but I'd like to just say "create a RecordFormat just like that File in that Library"

I did not see anything like that when looking at the RecordFormat and Record classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [AS400FileRecordDescription](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/access/AS400FileRecordDescription.html) class, specifically the [retrieveRecordFormat](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/access/AS400FileRecordDescription.html#retrieveRecordFormat()) method.

```
        AS400FileRecordDescription recordDescription = new AS400FileRecordDescription(
                as400, path);

        RecordFormat[] formats = recordDescription.retrieveRecordFormat();
```